# Clear Points and Replot a new one

Tags: openlayers, geojson, api, search, event-listener

Is it possible to reset or clear the map and plot new points? I have a search box that am using to query a geojson API.

After the first mapped result, the second search is plotted in addition which I do not want. What I want to achieve is, if I search, that result should be plotted not all subsequent searches I make.

Is there a way, to overwrite that first plotted result or remove it before plotting a new search result?

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    inputVal = input.value;
    // console.log(inputVal);
    getPointLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v1/dumela/' + inputVal,
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        }),
        style: styleFunction
    });

    var layersOnMap = map.getLayers();
    // reset the map, clear all point
    if (layersOnMap) {
        map.removeLayer(getPointLayer);
    }

    console.log(layersOnMap.length);
    map.addLayer(getPointLayer);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the little hack i did. I destroy the previous plot by `new ol.layer.Group` and then i called `map.addLayer(hgtmap)` again.

```
....

if (pointSource.getState() === "ready") {
    map.setLayerGroup(new ol.layer.Group());
    map.addLayer(hgtmap);
 }

 ....
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that there isn't a command to clear and redraw those points without keeping all subsequent points from your input. You can:

try calling `vectorLayer.redraw()`; afterward

Comment: redraw is not a function(), thats the error i get.. i did vectorLayer.redraw() and map.redraw() and all return this error. I would appreciate help link to the api documentation..

Comment: @saviour123 which version of OpenLayers are you using?

Comment: v4, the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `removeLayer()` clears the existing data. You should also be clearing the vector source when the function initializes. And if you do this I don't think removing layer is necessary unless you don't need it any more. If that doesn't work try adding the `removeLayer()` before the `getPointLayer` is defined.

Try adding `source.clear()` in the function as shown below. [Here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#clear)'s the api doc for this.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var layersOnMap = map.getLayers();
    // reset the map, clear all point
    if (layersOnMap) {
        map.removeLayer(getPointLayer);
    }
    //Clearing the source
    if(pointSource){
        pointSource.clear();
    }
    inputVal = input.value;
    // console.log(inputVal);
    pointSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v1/dumela/' + inputVal,
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    });

    getPointLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: pointSource,
        style: styleFunction
    });

    map.addLayer(getPointLayer);
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. But I found a solution now. check below